# jQuery autocomplete how to integrate this code with our function to validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using jQuery autocomplete in a zend project. The input displays a list of categories from our database. I just realized the form will still submit no matter what the user enters. I looked for a way to validate the field so they could only select an option from the database / autocomplete. I found this code which works

```
var src = ['hi', 'bye', 'foo', 'bar'];

$("#auto").autocomplete({ 
    source: function(request, response) {
        var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(src, request.term);

        if (!results.length) {
            this.element.val('');
        }
        response(results);
    }
});
```

My JS looks like this, i'm not sure how to use the code above to validate our variables coming from the autocomplete. Any help is appreciated thanks

```
$(function() {
    var url = "http://domain.com/account/ajaxautocomplete?format=json";
    $( "#autotest" ).autocomplete({
        source: url,
        minLength: 2
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using the wrong approach. You could use instead of the auto-completion a select-tag. Then the user can only make a valid selection and he knows what he can select.
But if you want to stick with the auto-completion you need to check the input independent from the auto-completion-tool (it's not intended for validation). You could check the data before it's send or with an keyup-event-listener.

Comment: The only reason for autocomplete is because there are a few thousands categories, so i'm looking for a way to let the user filter and quickly select a category.

Comment: The only solution I can think about is to add an keyup event listener and check if the entered input is valid. If it isn't you have to remove the chars from the end of the input until it's valid again and set the new valid string. So you can prevent that anything else is written into the field.

Comment: Just found this select widget which has a filter option so it should do what I need and force the user to select a category and filter the list http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/ didn't think to look for a select method, thanks